# Displaying different JS animation on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

Until min-height 1200px I have an HTML5 video, playing or stopping depending where you are on the page.

Then under 1200px you are suppose to have an images sequence, defined like this in the HTML :

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-xs-12 right">
        <video webkit-playsinline loop id="rightVideo" poster="{% static 'home_page/assets/videos/transparent.png' %}">
          <source src="{% static 'home_page/assets/videos/720x700.mp4' %}" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="{% static 'home_page/assets/videos/720x700.ogg' %}" type="video/ogg">
          <source src="{% static 'home_page/assets/videos/720x700.webm' %}" type="video/webm">
          Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
        <img alt="blippar blipp images sequence" id="images-sequence" src="">
</div>
```

Thus the images are load in JS and displaying with GSAP like this :

```
    this.imagesSequence = function(){
    var imageSeq = new TimelineMax({repeat: -1});
        imageSeq
            .to(obj, 25, {
                curImg: imagesSequenceNb.length - 1,
                roundProps: "curImg",
                immediateRender: true,
                ease: Linear.easeNone,
                onUpdate: function() {
                    //next image on update
                    sequence.src = imagesSequenceNb[obj.curImg];                    
                }
            }, 2);
};
```

Finally, I manage the different size screen:

```
if (window.innerWidth > 1200) {
  var imgPath = "{% static 'home_page/assets/' %}",
      myanimations = new homeAnimations(imgPath);

  myanimations.loadImages();
   {..code...}
} else if (window.innerWidth > 990 && window.innerWidth <= 1200) {
  var rightVideo = document.getElementById("rightVideo");

  rightVideo.play();
} else {
  var $nav_header = $(".navbar-fixed-top"),
      header_height = $('.navbar-fixed-top').height(),
      images_height = $('.header-plugin').height(),
      offset_val = images_height - header_height;
  var circleMobile = document.getElementById("circle-mobile");
  var birdVideo = document.getElementById("birdVideo");

  var imgPath = "{% static 'home_page/assets/' %}",
      myanimationsMobile = new homeAnimations(imgPath);

  myanimationsMobile.loadImages();
  myanimationsMobile.imagesSequence(); //I want to display this on resize !!

  birdVideo.play();

  TweenLite.to(circleMobile, 1, {rotation: 180});
}
```

So, if the screen is resize and then page is refreshing, no problem. But the transition isn't dynamic when you are resizing by hand the page..

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tryed to add a window.onresize function and in that check for window.innerWidth

Comment: The problem is my page is quite heavy, I don't know if it is the best to do.

Comment: Seemy awnser below for a waitForWinowResize() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have a dynamic control:

```
 window.onresize = function() {        
    if (window.innerWidth > 1200) {
      do somthing
    }
 };
```

That will dynamicly lisen for change.
Hope it helps.

If your site is hevy, make a timer like this to wait befor onresiz.

```
    function waitForWindowResize() {
        var rtime;
        var timeout = false;
        var delta = 200;

        function resizeend() {
            if (new Date().getTime() - rtime < delta) {
                setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
            } else {
                timeout = false;

                YOUR CODE HERE

            }
        }

        $(window).resize(function () {
            rtime = new Date();
            if (timeout === false) {
                timeout = true;
                setTimeout(resizeend, delta);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Awesome ! My page is heavy yes :)

Answer (score 1):

When will this code run? Put it into a window resize event handler like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    if (window.innerWidth > 1200) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it quite good except that I need to **resize** if I want to have some display **or** duplicate my code ??